# Method 'Iterable.forEach(Consumer<? super T>)' is not present in JRE Emulation Library

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt

I'm using IntelliJ for my GWT projects and for this code

```
LinkedList<String> modelValue = new LinkedList<>();
componentValue.forEach(product -> {
    Product p = (Product) product;
    modelValue.add(p.getObjectId());
});
```

I get this error:

```
Method 'Iterable.forEach(Consumer<? super T>)' is not present in JRE Emulation Library so it cannot be used in client code of 'com.mycompany.app.AppTest' GWT module less... (Ctrl+F1) 
This inspection reports usages in client code of JDK classes which are not present in the JRE Emulation Library.
```

How to fix this with IntelliJ?

Comment: There is opened issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119836

Answer (score 2):

You need to be using version 2.8 of GWT to use new API in Java 8, such as `Iterable.forEach()`.